# LNK2019 errors when using a static version of PoDoFo

Tags: c++, podofo

Hеllо,

I was wondering if I could request advice on the following issue. I am trying to include a static version of the PoDoFo library, but keep running up against a few LNK2019 errors. Below is an example of the error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument::Load(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > const &,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > const &)" (__imp_?Load@PdfMemDocument@PoDoFo@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function wmain Test <path>\main.obj 1
```

From the looks of it, the linker is trying to add functions from a dynamic library, and for the life of me I cannot understand why it does that.

Below are the particulars on how the PoDoFo library is constructed for the project:

- The version of the PoDoFo used is [the master one from GitHub](https://github.com/podofo/podofo);
- The dependencies are from [the set provided on GitHub](https://github.com/podofo/podofo-deps);
- The library's binary was generated with the parameter `PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC` set to `TRUE`;
- The version used is `MinSizeRel` (the release version of the minimum size);
- The main CMakeLists file was altered along the lines of the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75807248/unresolved-external-symbols-from-libxml-functions-when-compiling-podofo-in-visua);
- I am using the current version of the Visual Studio and the ISO C++ 2020 standard;

Below is the code of a test programme calling the library and some of its classes and methods:

```
// Static library switch
#ifndef PODOFO_STATIC
#define PODOFO_STATIC
#endif // !USING_SHARED_PODOFO

#include "..\..\external\PoDoFo\headers\PoDoFo\podofo.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument pdfIn;
    PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument pdfOut;

    pdfIn.Load("aaa123.pdf");
    pdfOut.Load("bbb123.pdf");

    pdfOut.GetPages().AppendDocumentPages(pdfIn);
    pdfOut.Save("new.pdf");

    _getwch();
}
```

Of note is the undefined macro `USING_SHARED_PODOFO` which is required for using a static version of the library.

Apart from undefining the `USING_SHARED_PODOFO` macro, I also have attempted defining `PODOFO_NO_DLL` as per one suggestion, but that has not helped either.

UPDATE:

Defining the macro `PODOFO_STATIC` has resolved the errors above, but produced new ones! They all seem to pertain to various functions defined in PoDoFo's dependencies. A typical example is below (this one comes from openssl):

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_CTX_new referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl PoDoFo::PdfEncryptMD5Base::GetMD5Binary(unsigned char const *,unsigned int,unsigned char *)" (?GetMD5Binary@PdfEncryptMD5Base@PoDoFo@@SAXPEBEIPEAE@Z) Test  <path>\Test\podofo.lib(PdfEncrypt.cpp.obj) 1
```

Would you happen to have any suggestions on how these can be resolved?

Comment: your defines need to be before rather than after the include

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, @AlanBirtles. The problem still stands though.

Comment: The `__declspec(dllimport)`  part means it's looking for an import library  (.lib) that comes with a dll.

Comment: Yes, @drescherjm, that is what I mentioned too: «From the looks of it, the linker is trying to add functions from a dynamic library», - but I just cannot see at all why that is happening.

Comment: https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/535a786f124b739e3c857529cecc29e4eeb79778/src/podofo/auxiliary/basedefs.h#L45

Comment: From the previous link it looks like `PODOFO_STATIC` needs to be defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, @HansPassant! That kind of worked: the errors are different now!
I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: The new error looks like openssl: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768071/openssl-linking-undefined-reference-evp-md-ctx-new-and-fre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768071/openssl-linking-undefined-reference-evp-md-ctx-new-and-fre) One negative to using static libraries is you need to link to all the libs that the static library depends on where you would not have to do that if you used dlls.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out, @drescherjm! That should solve it, I think.